# How does one determine what sequencing coverage/depth to use?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, statistics

In the context of rare diseases, what sequencing coverage will be sufficient to detect the mutated loci (for eg. SMN1, SMN2 CNVs, gene SNPS, INDELs etc) ? How does this relate to statistics and how one is confident of the results? Most commercial sequencing services are marketed as promising 95-99% at 20-30X. My question would be, how we arrive at these values. For example, why is 99% at 20X ideal and how are values derived mathematically?

Comment: "20-30x" sounds like depth rather than coverage...

Comment: OK, looks better. So, what do you think the % and X values mean in terms of sequencing?

Comment: % means the total coverage across all bases, while X is how much each base is sequenced.

Comment: Almost there. X is depth - number of times a base was covered by a sequence. So, what might those values mean in terms of sequence reliability?

Comment: Of course, I know that the higher the depth, the more reliable the sequence. I'm asking how the value itself is determined, whether 20X, 30X... 100X etc. How is it derived mathematically/statistically? Is it by calculating the power of the assay, confidence levels, binomial probability of errors, or...?

Comment: It's literally a count of the number of aligned sequences that cover that spot in the sequence. If you have 1 sequence that covers a base it is 1X, 10 = 10X etc. See: [Wikipedia on sequence coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverage_(genetics))

Comment: My question is, so why do some labs set the metric as 99% coverage at 20X? why would a benchmark of 20X be preferable over 10X for example? I'm not asking what 20X ,30X...vs 100X means, but the thought process behind setting this as a sequencing QC metric, and how it this is determined through statistics. Hope you get my question.

Comment: I don't know for sure as it will depend on the individual lab and their purpose, but 99% is about all you can achieve reasonably without repeating sequencing ($$$) and 20X coverage is enough to have reasonable certainty on a base - it's 5% error after all, which is the usual p value of 0.05 in statistics.